# How to just return two numbers after regex match with grep or sed?

Tags: sed, grep, xinput

I'm writing a shell script to run on startup that disables my tracking nub which has been acting up. I start with `xinput list`, which I pipe to `grep Stick` which I need to pipe to something like `grep id=` that gives me the two numbers, usually 11. the numbers are anywhere from 1 to 18 as far as I can tell, but I need to write something like `foo=xinput list | grep Stick | grep id=` and sets foo to 11. here is the example xinput list:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Toshiba input device                      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ TOSHIBA Web Camera - FHD                  id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

What I need to get is the number right after id= in the Stick line, 11.

Comment: You should include an example input and the corresponding desired output.

Comment: Got it. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @M.Loewenthal Wondering if grep/sed is necessary… if you tweak the question a bit there's a clear answer in specifying name (if known) to `xinput` as arg see answer added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, here is the command you want:

```bsh
foo="$(xinput list | grep -F 'Stick' | grep -Po '(?<=id=)\d\d?')"
```

A more detailed explanation follows.

---

You should be able to do what you want with `grep` and a regular expression which includes a [look-behind assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). The key ingredient is the following `grep` expression:

```bsh
grep -Po '(?<=id=)\d\d?'
```

This will match substrings which begin with `id=` and are followed by one or two digits, but will return only the digits and not the `id=` prefix.

Here is how you could test this out:

```bsh
echo "id=11" | grep -Po '(?<=id=)\d\d?'
```

This produces `11` as its output. Applying this to your code snippet yields the following:

```bsh
foo="$(xinput list | grep -F 'Stick' | grep -Po '(?<=id=)\d\d?')"
```

As a second test, suppose we put your example data into the file `data.txt`:

```
# data.txt
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Toshiba input device                      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ TOSHIBA Web Camera - FHD                  id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Then run the following command:

```bsh
cat data.txt | grep -F 'Stick' | grep -Po '(?<=id=)\d\d?'
```

This produces `11` as its output.

Answer (score 0):

#### Specify `AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick` to xinput

By specifying the device name, if known, `xinput` will `--list` only that device, which you can narrow to `--id-only`:

#### The command:

```
xinput --list --id-only 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick'
```

#### will return the ID value of specified device:

```
11
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually works better, but I want to get better at shell scripting, so I wanted to do it with grep, sed, etc. Thanks!